Receive notification of changing virtual machine size with Azure LogicApp

I'm all set up to get notifications by email and Slack when the size of the virtual machine changes. But I don't know how to get the old virtual machine size and the changed current virtual machine size.

When "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write" is triggered, you'll be notified of something, but the write option has too many notifications. I only want to be notified when the virtual machine size has changed.

The following is part of my code, but it doesn't work.


{
  "type": "If",
  "expression": {
    "or": [
      {
        "equals": [
          "@triggerBody()?['data']['operationName']",
          "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write"
        ]
      },
      {
        "equals": [
          "@triggerBody()?['data']['properties']['hardwareProfile']['vmSize']",
          "@triggerBody()?['data']['properties']['hardwareProfile']['vmSize']"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },


If you can't import the size of the past, or if you have to use too many codes, I'd like to get the current virtual machine size that has been changed. I need your help. And make sure to get a notification when the following two conditions are True. You need to change "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write" and "vmsize" to get the notification.

Simply "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write" should not be notified just because this command has been executed.
I ask for your help.

A better way to get resource changes, such as virtual machine size is using azure resource graph. reference
resourcechanges
| extend vmSize = properties.changes["properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize"], changeTime = todatetime(properties.changeAttributes.timestamp), targetResourceId = tostring(properties.targetResourceId), changeType = tostring(properties.changeType) 
| where isnotempty(vmSize) 
| order by changeTime desc 
| project changeTime, targetResourceId, changeType, properties.changes, previousSize = vmSize.previousValue, newSize = vmSize.newValue

output:


If you want using azure resource graph in logic app, you can use azure resource graph rest api. I have already coded a sample. But you need to pay attention to the authorization in http request in logic app. My example here directly applies the bearer token, you can also use managed identity instead.
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "HTTP_1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "query": "resourcechanges | extend vmSize = properties.changes['properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize'], changeTime = todatetime(properties.changeAttributes.timestamp), targetResourceId = tostring(properties.targetResourceId), changeType = tostring(properties.changeType)  | where isnotempty(vmSize) | order by changeTime desc | project changeTime, targetResourceId, changeType, properties.changes, previousSize = vmSize.previousValue, newSize = vmSize.newValue"
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiO*****Gs6m9iBfmQ",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "queries": {
                        "api-version": "2021-03-01"
                    },
                    "uri": "https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ResourceGraph/resources"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "contentTransfer": {
                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                    }
                },
                "type": "Http"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "correlation": {
                    "clientTrackingId": "wbtrackingId"
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {}
        }
    }
}

logic app output:


If you don't mind, could you show me the body sample of HTTP1?

hi @gotothesky, the http1 request body already exist in definition -> actions -> HTTP_1 -> inputs -> body. just look over the code I showed.

Can't I automatically detect and run the trigger?

You can create a simple logicapp, and add http post trigger.
